# Calling function in X seconds cleanly with no repeating

Tags: python

I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a function asynchronously in X time as a one-off without needing to clutter the app with a bunch of class variables to keep track of the timer or cancel the timer after the function is called.  Javascript can do this the easiest, so I'll show what I'd like to do in python using JS

```
setTimeout(function()
{
  //Do something in 1 second
}, 1000);
```

Basically, what I have now is:

```
class NeedyObject(QWidget):
  theTimer = None

  def process(self):
    self.theTimer =Timer(1,self.processCallback)
    self.theTimer.start()

  def processCallback(self):
    self.theTimer.cancel()
    #do something
```

I need to fire these one-off calls several times for a lot of different reasons and keeping track of every timer to cancel it isn't the way I'd like to do it.

How can I get this JS concept into Python?

Comment: use `threading.Timer`, drop the `cancel()` in the callback, and drop the unnecessary class-level variable.

Comment: ok so while I didn't use your suggestion, @roippi, it made me realize that I can simply spin up a thread and use a time.sleep to make it wait without blocking the main thread.  thanks for the nudge

Answer (score 1):

I noticed `QWidget` as a parameter to `NeedyObject`. If you're using Qt with Python bindings, maybe you could leverage a [single-shot QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot).

Comment: oh, nice, I'l give that a try

Comment: This is interesting but it required that the calling thread be called originally by QThread, which I don't want to do... appreciate the info though